# VSTest.Console.Exe does not execute tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, unit-testing, vstest

**vstest.console.exe does not execute my tests.**

```
            var testProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe",
                Arguments = _testDllPath,

                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
```

**I receive the following output when executing the commandline:**

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.60315.1Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

**NOTE:** Tests do get executed when I run MSTest:

```
        var testProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe",
                Arguments = string.Format(@"/testcontainer:""{0}"" /resultsfile:""{1}""", _testDllPath, _resultsDirectoryPath),

                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
```

**However, running mstest on the commandlline results in one of my tests failing even though I cannot reproduce the test failure in VS2012 TestExplorer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to surround my test dll path with quotes:

```
var testProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe",
        Arguments = _testDllPath.Replace(_testDllPath, '"' + _testDllPath + '"'),

        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```